# Delete unlocked rows/columns in unserinterfaceonly:=true mode

Tags: vba, excel, excel-interop

I protect certain cells with the following sub:

```
Sub test()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Locked = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C3:E8").Locked = True
Worksheets(1).Protect userinterfaceonly:=True
End Sub
```

My question is, **why isn't it possible to delete rows in the interface in the Locked=False range**?

E.g. I try to delete row 22, but that is not possible. I thought since I just locked cells till row 8, I can delete the others.

**Is there a way to achieve that?**

Comment: Have you checked to see if they are actually unlocked? And if the protected is allowing the select or delete unlocked cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the protection on a Sheet, you need to specify the rights that you allow to people :

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
```

So you should add `AllowDeletingRows:=True` when you protect the whole sheet before unlocking cells and locking range

Comment: You do not need to specify the rights. If there is none specified it will go with what ever was used last. Or the default one if none has been used before

Comment: Yup so if you don't set it, you almost have no clue of what it'll accept or not, so it's better to specify it when it doesn't do what you want

Comment: If you don't set it it will be the default which is just `Select locked cells` and `select unlocked cells`. So you do know what it will be. Or, as I said, it will be what ever they used last. They might of been doing it manually to start with, have the correct protection ready and just want to use that. It would be safer to specify each protection you want. However it will still work without and as long as it is only them using the sheet they will know if it changes